# How to create a user ability to save pages with full url?

Tags: urls, save-post

Problem: I have a real estate website with dynamic pages.  For example when you click on a property it links to http://example.com/property/?id=23432434.  I want to give users the ability to save a property.  I have tried many plugins that offer saving posts but none save the full url and will only save http://example.com/property/.

Does anyone know of a way to implement this? I found $current_url is the full url and I have tried to edit some plugins by changing $postid to this with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Change paramalink to post name it will shows post name in url and it's stable link.

Comment: @M.Idrish Thanks for the reply!  This is for a Page and not an actual Post so changing the permalink doesn't help.

Comment: How do the other plugins do it? I expect you can adapt that. I'd guess you just need to save the property IDs in user_meta, and you'd probably need to set up a REST API endpoint or admin-ajax method to set or clear a favourite, then you'll need a user admin page to list their favourites, and you'd want a way to show that a given property is a favourite or not on the page itself, which you might also have to do client side depending on what caching you have on your site.